# Mockito: HttpServeletRequest return mock Cookie not working as expected

Tags: spring-mvc, cookies, mockito

I have a method `hello(HttpServletRequest request)` that needs to be unit tested. In this method, I do something like this `Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, cookie_name)`. So basically, I extract the cookie here and do my stuff. This is how my test class looks like:

```
@Test
public void testHello() {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookie_name, "");
    Mockito.when(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(new Cookie[]{cookie});
    Mockito.when(WebUtils.getCookie(request, cookie_name)).thenReturn(cookie);
    // call the hello(request) and do assert
}
```

So whenever I try to mock and return this cookie, I end up with something like this in my stack trace.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Cookie cannot be returned by getCookies()
getCookies() should return Cookie[]
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

Inside `WebUtils.getCookie()`, it basically does `request.getCookies()` and iterates the array to get the correct one. This WebUtils comes from Spring Web. As you can see I have returned some value for that as well. Still getting this error. Has anyone faced this issue? How can I workaround this?

Comment: WebUtils.getCookie() is a static method. You will not be able to mock it using Mockito. Also, if you have mocked request object and then creating a stub for request.getCookies method then you do not need to stub WebUtils.getCookie() method again.

Comment: Cant understand what you mean by stub. Can you link some examples or show how it can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on @Ajinkya comment, I think this is what he wanted to express:

---

The getCookie method might looks something like this (I just used some version of it, so there might have been some changes in the version you are using)

```
public static Cookie getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, String name) {
        Assert.notNull(request, "Request must not be null");
        Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (name.equals(cookie.getName())) {
                    return cookie;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Since you mocked your request you can control what getCookies() is returning.
To make this method working (without mocking it), you just would need to return a mock instead of a real Cookie from `getCookies()`.

```
    Cookie mockCookie = Mockito.mock(Cookie.class);
    Mockito.when(mockCookie.getName()).thenReturn(cookie_name);    

    Mockito.when(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(new Cookie[]{mockCookie});
```

Changing it to this and the static method can do its work as usual.
 You wouldn't need bother mocking it.

Comment: Thanks @second. This is exactly what I meant.